# How can I prevent all my text in html from being all bold?

Tags: html, bold

So I made an html document and everything is showing up as bold, I am new to html and I don't know how to fix this problem, help would be much appreciated.

edit: sorry i forgot to post the code, here it is:

I've tried all I could to fix it and there are no posts online (that I know of) that have the same problem.

Any help would be much appreciated for me to start my career and to continue working with this company.

Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <style> body { border: solid 2px;} </style>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>
     Service Completion
 </title>
 <h1 align="center">
     <img src="https://image4.owler.com/logo/gbm_owler_20190819_065656_original.png" 
     alt="Error 404: File Not Found!" 
     width="238" height="63">
 </h1>
<font size="5">
 <h1 align="center">
     <b>
         <u>
             SERVICES COMPLETION FORM
         </u>
     </b>
 </h1>
</font>


</head>
<body>
    <font size="5">
        <strong>
            <h2>
                <u>
                    <i>
                        Customer Information
                     </i>
                 </u>
             </h2>
         </strong>
     </font>
     <strong>
   <font size="5" align="center">
       <table border="1" align="center"  border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" Style="width:50%" align="left" span style="height:100% ; width:100%">
                Customer Name:     
             </th>
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <td Style="width:50%" align="left" span style="height:100% ; width:100%">
                    Customer Contact:     
                 </td>
                 <td Style="width:50%" align="left" span style="height:100% ; width:100%">
                     Contact Telephone:     
                 </td>
             </tr>
     <tr>
         <td Style="width:50%" align="left" span style="height:100% ; width:100%">
             Service:     
         </td>
         <td Style="width:50%" align="left" span style="height:100% ; width:100%">
             Project Number:     
         </td>
     </tr>
 </font>
</strong>
    </table>

<font size="5" align="left">
     <strong>
         <h2>
             <u>
                 <i>
                     Scope of Services
                  </i>
              </u>
          </h2>
      </strong>
  </font>

  The signature below indicates concurrence that the specified tasks have been completed as per the SoW.
  <table align="center" border="1"  border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
      <tr>
          <th align="left" Style="width:50%">
             <strong>
                 Milestone 3 : Installation and Configuration
             </strong>
             </th>
             <td Style="width:50%">
             <strong>
                 Completed :
             </strong> 
             </td>
         </tr>
<tr>
 <td Style="width:50%" align="left">
     Installation and Configuration completed for
     <ul align="left">
         <li>
             Non-production environment
         </li>
         <li>
             Production environment
         </li>
         <li>
             Integration with Office Online
         </li>
         <li>
             Integration with web services (IAM, OPMS, Maximo & GRC
         </li>
         <li>
             Installation and Configuration Documentation
         </li>
     </ul>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

<font size="5" align="left">
 <strong>
     <h2>
         <u>
             <i>
                 Comments
              </i>
          </u>
      </h2>
  </strong>
</font>
<table align="center" border="1"  border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
 <tr>
     <th Style="width:50%">
     </th>
 </tr>
</table>
<font size="5" align="left">
 <strong>
     <h2>
         <u>
             <i>
                 Evaluation
              </i>
          </u>
      </h2>
  </strong>
</font>
<form align="left">
 Please specify whether the service has been delivered to your satisfaction or not:
 <lebal>
     Yes
 </lebal>
 <input type="radio" name="a">
 <label>
     No
 </label>
 <input type="radio" name="a">
</form>

<form align="left">
Please specify whether the service can be billed:
<lebal>
 Yes
</lebal>
<input type="radio" name="a">
<label>
 No
</label>
<input type="radio" name="a">
</form>

<font size="5" align="left">
 <strong>
     <h2>
         <u>
             <i>
                 Customer Authorized Signature
              </i>
          </u>
      </h2>
  </strong>
</font>
The signature below indicates concurrence that the specified service has been accepted/completed.
<table align="center" border="1"  border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
 <tr>
     <th align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Name:
     </th>
     <th align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Title:
     </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Signature:
     </td>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Date:
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Name:
     </td>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Title:
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Signature:
     </td>
     <td align="left" Style="width:50%">
         Date:
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: You should post some code and what you have done till now for us to better understand and reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

For not important text's you can use span or p Elements.
Strong and B elements are for bold content

Or you can control the weight of text using css:

font-weight: normal;

Complete information about font-weight :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your strong tags, this is used to define text with strong importance and is typically displayed in bold.